# Trying to copy files between two different servers

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to copy one file from stage host to dev host by using following command in UNIX box. However I am getting an error "no such file or directory".

```
$ scp [-r] [[user@]xxx-stage.example.com:]/apps/usr/example/example.html [[user@]xxx-dev.example.com:]/apps/usr/example
```

> [[user@]xxx-dev.example.com:]/apps/usr/example: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to replace all of the placeholder text with what's supposed to go there........

Comment: @Will
Can you give an example what need to be replaced

Comment: see here: https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc

Comment: @Will Its working now i am able to transfer file between two servers
Thanks

Comment: Awesome! No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
ssh -A -t user@remote1 scp /tmp/example.html user@remote2:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

scp -r  ipaddress:file    ipaddress2:desired location